# timed out while receiving the initial server greeting

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, mail-command

I'm trying to host a postfix mail server.I have a box with a fixed IP and also a mx record and spf record that link my box IP to my dns record. I can telnet to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25 but when I send a mail to me@gmail.com, I still receive this error

**mailq**

```
-Queue ID-  --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
CB502D9735*     389 Tue Jul 18 01:28:17  root@mydomain.com
                                         me@gmail.com

37A54D8C06      389 Tue Jul 18 00:26:34  root@mydomain.com
(conversation with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.26] timed out while receiving the initial server greeting)
                                         me@gmail.com


BBC43D9557      389 Tue Jul 18 01:11:20  root@mydomain.com
(conversation with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.200.26] timed out while receiving the initial server greeting)
                                         me@gmail.com
```

```
telnet alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25


Trying 74.125.200.27...
Connected to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: So your telnet also didn't receive the "initial server greeting". Usually it's your ISP that prevents this. You're supposed to connect to your ISP's server which will relay to the destination.

Comment: I can connect via telnet on the Gmail mail server

Comment: You don't get it: the time out is not about the ability to connect. It's the fact that when you connect you don't receive the server greeting. You're supposed to receive a line like `220 someserver ESMTP ...` but you don't. If you actually do, that's something to [add in the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/751749/edit). You should also describe where is this fixed IP of yours: a normal ISP, a hosting provider (which one) etc. But This might not have much to do with running postfix if you can reproduce it with telnet.

Comment: I have also a nat configured but I have only outbound traffic authorization on this firewall. Since I initiated the session I think it must pass through firewall. Can this be the issue

Comment: Last and final attempt: did you or didn't you receive the server greeting with telnet?

Comment: I did not receive any greeting